# Не получается установить nvidia-driver

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu

Во время установки cuda, появляется следующая ошибка:

```
[INFO]: Setting silent=true
[INFO]: Silent install of all components
[INFO]: Driver not installed.
[INFO]: Checking compiler version...
[INFO]: gcc location: /bin/gcc

[INFO]: gcc version: gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)

[INFO]: Initializing menu
[INFO]: Components to install:
[INFO]: Driver
[INFO]: 418.87.00
[INFO]: Executing NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.87.00.run --ui=none --no-questions --accept-license --disable-nouveau --no-cc-version-check --install-libglvnd  2>&1
[INFO]: Finished with code: 256
[ERROR]: Install of driver component failed.
[ERROR]: Install of 418.87.00 failed, quitting
```

Следует отметить, что установка происходит при помощи [run-file](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=runfilelocal).

Предыдущие попытки установить nvidia-smi, например, выдавали:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Comment: А почему бы не установить драйвер из штатных репозиториев дистрибутива? Или он настолько экзотический, что в нём нет драйвера?

Comment: @andreymal так я оттуда и устанавливал, в т.ч.